# Error when rebuilding search index in ElasticSearch/Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch

When I run

```
./manage.py search_index --rebuild
```

I get the following error:

```
 elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [bodystyle : {type=text}] [model : {type=text}] [carclass : {type=text}] [version : {type=text}]')
```

I have tried to change the version of my elasticsearch. My current version is:

$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "MOkbeEQ",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "pF_Z62bBTl-Jq31HSuAhQA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.8",
    "build_hash" : "688ecce",
    "build_date" : "2018-02-16T16:46:30.010Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

My documents.py code is as below:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from products.models import Product_Model


@registry.register_document
class CarDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        # Name of the Elasticsearch index
        name = 'cars'
        # See Elasticsearch Indices API reference for available settings
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                    'number_of_replicas': 0}

class Django:
    model = Product_Model # The model associated with this Document

    # The fields of the model you want to be indexed in Elasticsearch
    fields = [
        'model',
        'version',
        'carclass',
        'bodystyle',
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you migrating to elasticsearch version 6/7?
try to upgrade your `django_elasticsearch_dsl` version